# Как получить название ключа JSON в Python?

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста. Возможно, вопрос глупый, но все таки. **Как получить название ключа("Текст")?** Или это нереально?)

```json
[{
    "Текст": {
        "enabled": false,
        "type:": "state"
    },
    "Текст2": {
        "enabled": false,
        "type:": "state"
    },
    "Текст3": {
        "enabled": false,
        "type:": "state"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Это некорректный `JSON`, каких-то скобок снаружи не хватает, видимо фигурных, но, возможно, что-то ещё отрезано кроме них?

Comment: да, я знаю, что некорректный, нехватает еще квадратных кавычек в начале самом и в конце.

Comment: Так они там есть или нет? Если есть - добавьте, если нет - так и напишите, что у вас в наличии некорректный `JSON`. Чтобы понятно было, с чем мы имеем дело.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас подправлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем `json`, чтобы преобразовать строковую последовательность в релевантный словарь `python`

```py
from json import loads

json_ = '''{"Текст":{
    "enabled": false,
    "type:": "state"
    }}'''

dict_from_json = loads(json_)
```

А далее как советовали

```py
for key in dict_from_json:
    print(key)
```

Применять метод `keys()` для словаря опционально и не обязательно для данной задачи

Относительно обновленных данных все то же самое, с отступлением, что это список словарей

```py
from json import loads
a = '''[{
    "Текст": {
        "enabled": false,
        "type:": "state"
    },
    "Текст2": {
        "enabled": false,
        "type:": "state"
    },
    "Текст3": {
        "enabled": false,
        "type:": "state"
    }
}]'''

# в список словарей 
list_from_json = loads(a)

all_keys = []

# все ключи
for item in list_from_json:
    all_keys += item.keys()
```

Ну, а поскольку список содержит всего одну запись, то можно и вот так собрать ключи

```py
all_keys = list(list_from_json[0].keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = d.keys()
for key in d:
   print(key) # название ключа
```

Comment: то есть, вы предлагаете читать json Как обычный словарь и публикуете несуразный код? зачем вы присваиваете переменной name ключи словаря d, а поток к словарю d и обращаетесь?